# cucumber files not loading

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

I'm doing this cucumber tutorial on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_annotations.htm

and they told me to add some dependencies to my pom file: selenium-java, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit and junit. Here's my pom:

[image: pom file]

Then they asked me to create a feature file: annotation.feature and a step definitions file: annotation.java.

However when I create annotation.java I get this error message that says, "The import cucumber.annotation.en.Given cannot be resolved:

[image: annotation file]

However, cucumber is in my maven dependencies:

[image]

So why is it saying that the import cannot be resolved?

Comment: Please note that you're using a very old version of Cucumber. I'd highly recommend going to a more recent version (v2.4.0 atm). Note that the groupId changed to `io.cucumber` as of v2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your test directory is not in eclipse project classpath. Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build path and add it. Also, `mvn clean install` sometimes helps

Comment: Your project looks a bit weird I think. I see 2 folders src at the same level? Or am I confused? Also sometimes versions matter a lot, maybe this tutorial is using java7 and you might be using another version ?